# Calculating the integral of a circlish curve

Tags: calculus

[image]

How do i calculate the red area dependent of the x value?
Does $x^2+y^2=r^2$ help me here or maybe the integral of it? (solved for y, since r is given)

Edit: even tho its an ellipse it should be treated like a circle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you solve the equation for the circle (or ellipse) you get $y = \pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.  The negative solution $y=-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ is the bottom half of your circle.  You can then take the integral of this equation between your bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The area of a circle of radius $r$ is $\pi r^2$. The area of the square as shown in the diagram is $(2r)^2$. Let $A$ be the quantity desired. Then we have $4A = (2r)^2 - \pi r^2$. No integral is required.